# How to grab the value of a dropDownList in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I am not grabbing the selected value ($model->attribute) on a dropDownList in Yii2, what could be wrong? Thanks

This is the code that is located on a View:

```
    $command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT att1 
                                             FROM table
                                                ORDER By table_id ASC');
    $rows = $command->queryAll();
    $command->execute();

    $listData = ArrayHelper::index($rows, null, 'table_id');
```

Then on the same View I call to $listData

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9"> 

            <?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>

            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'test-form', 'options' => ['data-pjax' => true]
            ]); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'attribute')->dropDownList($listData, ['prompt'=>'List of attributes.']); ?>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'test-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>

        </div>
 </div>
```

This is the Controller:

```
public function actionTest()
    {
        $model = new TestForm();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
                    $model->insertTest();
                 return $this->renderAjax('test', ['model' => $model]);       

            } else {
                return $this->renderAjax('test', ['model' => $model]);
            }

    }
```

The Model has the definition of $attribute and insertTest() is a function that use the value of $attribute to query onto a DB.

Comment: You need to show us how you initiate the `$model`. Probably in the Controller and loads from the POST/GET request .. ?

Answer (score 2):

Thinking of you should use

`ArrayHelper::map($listData, 'table_id', 'table_id');`

Because you need a one-dimensional array.

And it's better to use the ActiveRecord for queries to the database.

[ArrayHelper Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html#building-maps)

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting only `att1` from table so you should map this column

```
$listData = ArrayHelper::index($rows, 'att1');
```

for debug try modify your actionTest commenting $model->insertTest(); and using   $model->save(); 
if the value is saved  in db then you should check  inside you $model->insertTest() function

```
  public function actionTest()
  {
      $model = new TestForm();

          if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
                // $model->insertTest();
               $model->save();
               return $this->renderAjax('test', ['model' => $model]);       

          } else {
              return $this->renderAjax('test', ['model' => $model]);
          }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its a better way to generate the list for the dropDownList, however the issue still at the moment of grabbing the selected value from <?= $form->field($model, 'attribute')->dropDownList($listData, ['prompt'=>'List of attributes.']); ?>

Comment: what's your problem .. you have not data in list?   .. you have not value when submit ?  .. explain better please

Comment: The dropDownList displays a list of values like this: 0 \n attribute1 1 \n attribute2 2 \n attribute3 3 \n attribute4 ...  The problem is that if I select attribute3 for example that value is not being grabbed by the variable $attribute after the submit. What could I have been doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Update your question and show your related controller action so i can evaluate the code that get the result of the submit

Comment: how you check the the value submitted is not  "grabbed"   .. have you tried var_dump($model) before the $model->insertTest() ?? ..  and what do the insertTest() function .. ?

Comment: I did var_dump($model) before the $model->insertTest() and it returned ["attribute"]=> string(13) "att1" So it already has a value which comes from the first Select from the View that is before the submit, the issue is that is not doing any submit and the variable has a value before the latter, how can overcome that issue? Thanks

Comment: then you have the value selected but don't save  the value in db  right ?

Comment: Yes, no value is saved in the DB.

Comment: i have added  some code  .. for check  .. let me know

Comment: I put  $model->save(); on the Controller and on the Debug page I see $_POST
Empty.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

you should use map in ArrayHelper

```
$listdata = ArrayHelper::map(CategoryModel::find()->orderBy(['table_id' => SORT_ASC])->all(), 'table_id', 'table_text');
```

Note: 'table_text' is table attribute that will appear in dropdown label.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to that issue.

By doing this way the form was not able to save the submitted information.

```
   $command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT att1 
                                                 FROM table
                                                    ORDER By table_id ASC');
   $rows = $command->queryAll();
   $command->execute();

  $listData = ArrayHelper::index($rows, null, 'table_id');
```

However, by this way the form is able to grab the value selected and put it into the variable.

```
$rows = table::find()->all();
$listData = ArrayHelper::map($rows,'table_id','att1');
```